# how to take value from partial view to parent view without refreshing the page in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i'm new in asp.net mvc 3.my question is how to take values which is  in partial view that is jquery dailog form  to parent view without refreshing the page in asp.net mvc 3.

Comment: If You need something from partialView in parent View it means You did something wrong-situation like this one shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

..via a client side technology, e.g: jQuery. You have to pass the result of any results from the partial view into the layout via javascript. You can't re-inject dynamic data into a page, after a form submission, completely via server-side technologies.

The [Ajax.BeginForm() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform.aspx) allows you to supply a javascript function to call once it has successfully returned some data:

```
function postSuccess(returned_data) {
    alert(returned_data);
}
```

You can use that to inject your controller supplied data into your page.

Comment: can u provide an example if possible?

Comment: Provided the success function prototype, since that's notoriously hard to find an up-to-date version of.